# how to convert the electron app into single packager installer(only executable) in linux?

Tags: angular, electron, packaging, software-distribution, electron-packager

I have created Desktop app into linux app with supporting files,now i wanted to make into single file (executable),so that it can be share to anyone.
Is there way to make it into executable file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging **any** app on **any** platform needs some libraries, wether static or dynamically linked. Packaging into one single executable file will never work, at least with Electron.

Packaging your Node.js Electron source files into an executable (also known as compiling) is easy - if you use [`electron-packager`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager). That's a Node.js "plugin" you can install (and save as dev-dependency) via NPM with the following command:

`npm install --save-dev electron-packager`

Next, you can create a "build" script inside your `package.json` like that:

```
"scripts": {
  "build-linux64": "electron-packager . ProjectName --platform=linux --arch=x64"
}
```

This script will compile your project for a 64-bit Linux system. For other switches, please refer to the electron-packager documentation, as available [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/readme.md).

After that, there should be a folder called `ProjectName-platform-arch` in your project's main directory, which you can zip up and distribute. This executable (`ProjectName` in the output folder) will then be executable on any 64-bit Linux OS **without** Node.js installed.

But, to mention it at least, this is ***not*** an installer. For Linux you can build a "package", like `*.deb` for Debian/Ubuntu and derivates, `*.rpm` for RedHat, OpenSuSE, SLES, SLED, Fedora and derivates or `*.tar.gz` for plain source code packages (like `apt` uses). This can't be achieved with `electron-packager` but with the on-board tools of your Linux OS. There are some great tutorials on how to build Linux packages in the net out there, but this certainly goes far out of the boundaries of this answer.